# upload image then share without saving the file on Flex using sharedObject or anything?

Tags: apache-flex, image, sharing

I'm currently working on a chat with uploading an image and sharing it. The problem is I can upload and display the image but I can't share it to the other side.

Here is some code:

```
public var photo:FileReference = new FileReference();

protected function crop_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var f:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Image", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*;*.gif;*.png;*");
    photo.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
    photo.browse([f]);
}

private function fileSelected(evt:Event):void
{
    photo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadCompleted);
    photo.load();
}

private var loader : Loader = new Loader();

private function loadCompleted(evt:Event):void
{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getBitmapData);
    loader.loadBytes(photo.data);
}

private function getBitmapData(event:Event):void
{
    var content:* = loader.content;
    var BMPData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(content.width,content.height);

    var UIMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    BMPData.draw(content, UIMatrix);

    var imgObj:Object = new Object();
    imgObj.client = username.text;
    imgObj.img = BMPData;
    imgSO.setProperty("image",imgObj);
}           

private function imagehandler(SEvt:SyncEvent):void
{
    if(imgSO.data.image)
    {
        var imgObj:Object = imgSO.data.image;
        var p:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
        var image:InlineGraphicElement = new InlineGraphicElement();

        image.source = new Bitmap(imgObj.img);
        p.addChild(senderName(imgObj.client));
        p.addChild(image);
        chatWindow.textFlow.addChild(p);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you target Flash Player 10, you can try using the [`FileReference`](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/25/saving-files-locally-using-the-filereference-classs-save-method-in-flash-player-10/) class. Quick (untested) example:

```
protected function exportImage():void
{
  var imageToSave:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(image, 300, new PNGEncoder());
  var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
  file.save(imageToSave.data, "my_image_name.png");
}
```

Comment: ooops please ignore the classname i forgot to change it. what i mean is i need to upload and share an image to the other user(real time). thanks for the response.